# There is some $N\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|f(x_n)| \geq \frac{|f(x)|}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a convergent sequence in $\Bbb R$ with $\lim \limits_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ and $f(x)\ne 0$

I want to prove that there is some $N\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $|f(x_n)| \geq \frac{|f(x)|}{2}$ for all $n\geq N$

---

I think I should do this by proving that for a continuous $f$, $x_n\to x \implies f(x_n)\to f(x)$, and then using that to prove the statement.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

By definition of continuity, if you take $\varepsilon=\frac{|f(x)|}{2}$, there is a $N\in \mathbb Z^+$ such that if $n\geq N$,
$$|f(x)|-|f(x_n)|\leq|f(x)-f(x_n)|\leq \frac{|f(x)|}{2}\implies |f(x_n)|\geq \frac{|f(x)|}{2}.$$

**Added**

By continuity,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty }f(x_n)=f(x),$$

and thus, 
$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists N\in \mathbb Z^+: \forall n\in\mathbb Z^+, n\geq N\implies  |f(x)-f(x_n)|<\varepsilon.$$

In particular, if you take $\varepsilon=\frac{|f(x)|}{2}$ there is a $N\in\mathbb Z^+$ such that if $n\geq N$
$$|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\frac{|f(x)|}{2}.$$

Comment: Are you referring to Weierstrass's definition?

$|x-c|\lt \delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|\lt \epsilon$

Comment: I'm just using the theorem$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)\iff \forall (x_n): x_n\to a, \lim_{n\to\infty }f(x_n)=f(a).$$ But I of course also use your definition...

Comment: I just couldn't see where you used the epsilon that you set

Comment: I completed my answer.